# Programmatically change Tabs when using idTabs

Tags: jquery-plugins

I want to have the actual idtab button aswell as a link/button within the tab able to change tabs via JavaScript.

Is this possible if so how?
Thanks

Comment: Not sure at all what you are talking about? What actual tab? Can you post some code?

Comment: The plugin and code examples can be found here http://www.sunsean.com/idTabs/

Answer (score 1):

after looking through the examples again I have re-used the bulk of it and I have come up with the following

```
  function switchTab(ActiveTab) {
        var set = $('.idtabs').html();   

        $("a", set).removeClass("selected")
        .filter("[href='" + ActiveTab + "']", set).addClass("selected");

        $.each($("a", set), function (key, value) {
            $($(value).attr("href")).hide();
        });

        $(ActiveTab).show();}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just stumbled through your post after a google search. In case anyone else arrives here through the same way, I'll let an advice.

Instead of...

```
$("a", set).removeClass("selected")
```

...and...

```
$.each($("a", set), function (key, value) {
```

...one should use:

```
$("yourMenu#IdOrHTMLTag a")
```

It will prevent the code from calling jQuery's `.hide()` and `.removeClass` at all links of the page, which would raise an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want just triggering the link's click event:

```
function switchTab(ActiveTab) {
    $("a[href'"+ActiveTab+"']").click();
}
```